# GL_DEPTH_TEST doens't work

Tags: java, android, 3d, geometry, opengl-es-2.0

So, here is my 3D cube code:

```
Mesh cube = new Mesh(false, 8, 36,
        new VertexAttribute(VertexAttribute.POSITION, 3, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE),
        new VertexAttribute(VertexAttribute.COLOR_PACKED, 4, ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE)
    );

float x = -100;
float y = -50;
float z = 250;

float w = 50;
float h = 50;
float l = 50;

float r = Color.RED.toFloatBits();
float g = Color.GREEN.toFloatBits();
float b = Color.BLUE.toFloatBits();

float[] vertices = {
    -w / 2f + x, y, l / 2f + z,  // 0
    r,
    -w / 2f + x, h + y, l / 2f + z, // 1
    r,
    w / 2f + x, h + y, l / 2f + z, // 2
    b,
    w / 2f + x, y, l / 2f + z, // 3
    b,

    w / 2f + x, y, -l / 2f + z, // 4
    g,
    w / 2f + x, y + h, -l / 2f + z, // 5
    g,
    -w / 2f + x, y + h, -l / 2f + z, // 6
    r,
    -w / 2f + x, y, -l / 2f + z, // 7
    r
};

short[] indices = {
    0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0,
    3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 3,
    4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4,
    7, 6, 1, 1, 0, 7,
    0, 3, 4, 4, 7, 0,
    1, 6, 5, 5, 2, 1
};

cube.setIndices(indices);
cube.setVertices(vertices);
```

"Prototype":
[image]

Mesh class is from LibGDX and it's modified by me (not too much).
First of all, I calling

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

at initialization (after init context, of course).

And render method looks like this:

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

shaderProgram.begin();
cube.render(shaderProgram, GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
shaderProgram.end();
```

And final result is:
[image]

I've also played with glDepthFunc, but I didn't get desired result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an error after calling glEnable?

Comment: what are the values of znear and zfar?

Comment: @DanP near: 0, far: 1000

Comment: The reason I asked is if you set the range of zfar-znear too high, the depth of some triangles will be mapped to the same depth value. which I think is not the case. I'm also wondering since I don't see the entire code, maybe glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) is called somewhere (maybe in shaderProgram.begin()) ?

Also if you want the cube to be shown, Cull test can do the job by hiding back facing triangles.

Comment: 0 is actually a really bad value for the near distance. This should be a positive value. Try 1 instead. Also, make sure that you actually have a depth buffer.

Comment: Only 2 reasons would be the cause, If you Culling Face normals of the vertex may in reverse direction,

Comment: @DanP I forgot to do 2 things:
'setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);' and 'near = 1;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, that I'm forgot to set up depth buffer size at creating Open GL context:

```
setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
```

Also, `near` value should be > 0, so I set it up to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Only 2 reasons would be the cause,

1)  If you enabled Culling and the Face normal of the triangle is in reverse direction,then the triangle will not be rendered.Use cross product to calculate face normal of the triangle.

2) If the depth function is wrong.

To Calculate face/surface normal of the triangle refer http://fullonsoftware.co.uk/snippets/content/Math_-_Calculating_Face_Normals.pdf

Comment: Also, 'near' should be > 0